# Installing Debian buster 10.5 on VirtualBox 6.1

Tags: virtualbox, debian-buster

I would like to install Debian buster 10.5 on VirtualBox 6.1.

[image]

I have the virtual machine booting from the netinst iso but after choosing *graphical install* the VM's screen goes black and nothing happens.

[image]

Any ideas?!

Comment: `ubuntu-20.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso` gets as far as a blinking cursor :/

Comment: Is it something to do with this in the logs? `00:00:03.470772 HM: HMR3Init: Attempting fall back to NEM: VT-x is not available`

Comment: Something called "Hyper-V" may also be relevant, but ultimately it seems that VirtualBox cannot be used on a machine that has Docker working.

Comment: may occur because of three reasons : VT-x is not enabled in the BIOS; 
The CPU doesn't support VT-x;
Hyper-V virtualization is enabled in Windows

Comment: Hyper-V is on in Windows and turning itniff

Comment: Hyper-V is on in Windows and turning it off prevents Docker from working. It appears that VitrualBox cannot be used on a machine thatbhas docker, and I use docker so therefore I can't have Virtual Box. What utter shit.