# How to use Virtualbox 6.1 under Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox

I struggle around with that issue for days now. I cant run any virtual machine in windows 10. Some days ago, at one of my first attempts i remember, the console told something about spectre so i read a little bit about that. Found a lot of stuff like some batch scripts and stuff. Some say Hyper-V must be anabled, others say it must be disabled. Some say you cant use docker and virtualbox on the same machine..

in short terms, i am totally confused now. What has changed?!? I use VB for years and never had those troubles.

The comments in [Installing Debian buster 10.5 on VirtualBox 6.1](https://superuser.com/questions/1582698/installing-debian-buster-10-5-on-virtualbox-6-1) seems to me like its a difference between enabling Hyper-V in Bios or in windows itself, so i tried both. Without success, the boot process just hang, no matter if i use live-cd, installer or pre-installed vdisk.

So how to use Virtualbox in Windows 10?

**Edit** I tried @John s suggestion.

- Dsable HyperV (Windows Features)
- deinstall virtualbox
- Enable HyperV in Bios
- reinstall VirtualBox

Now i got another error than before [an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pW8jU.png)

Comment: Disable Hyper-V (Windows Features), uninstall Virtual Box, go into BIOS and make sure hardware virtualization (VT-x) has been enabled (most guests today are 64-bit). Restart, install Virtual Box and try again. I am posting this from a Kali guest in VMware Workstation.

Comment: "the console told something about spectre".   The exact error message would be needed to help you.  Just download the Windows exe from virtualbox.org and start it.

Comment: Instead of disabling Hyper-V just upgrading to 2004 or 20H2 and enable Hypervisor Platform.

Comment: @John i tried exactly the steps you told me. I added a screenshot to my question.

Comment: Try a different guest machine (different Linux) to see if it is your guest or if it is VBOX causing the issue.

Comment: I tried debian, ubuntu and kali. debian/ubuntu just freezes screen, kali gives the message in the image. Should i upload vbox.log here or on some pastebin?

Comment: Check your BIOS settings. I am am not sure if "Hyper-V" in BIOS is the same as VT-x.   It is possible (again not sure) that your board does not support VT-x.  Uploading long logs does not usually help. See if you can find the error in the log.

Comment: If i could i would not ask here, sry :P